# VMX downgrade using ovf manipulation

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-esxi, linux-networking

I have problem with ubuntu when downgrade VMX-13 on ESXi 6.5 to VMX-11 on ESXi 6.0
when the machine powered on, network card is up but 100% packet lost.

the convert process is :

Step 1 – edit the ovf file:

```
open the .ovf file with an editor
find the line <vssd:VirtualSystemType>vmx-10</vssd:VirtualSystemType>
change vmx-10 to eg. vmx-07 (or another hw-version working with your ESXi)
save the changes
```

Step 2 – calculate SHA-1 and change .mf file:

Now you have to replace the corresponding SHA-1 of the edited OVF file in the .mf file:

If you have a hashing utility, calculate the SHA-1 of the edited .ovf file and replace the hash in the .mf file.
Then the import of the OVF Template should work without any problems/errors.

If you do not have an hashing utility, download one. You can use eg. “HashmyFiles” from NirSoft if you want.

Comment: Please describe in more detail how you did the "downgrade process".

Comment: The easiest way for this process would be to use the VMware converter.

Comment: Hi Gerald , i edit the question and add convert process